# How to properly deal with encrypted Word and Excel documents for viewing in a UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, excel, uiwebview, ms-word, credentials

I have a `UIWebView` that works fine for viewing an ***unencrypted*** Word or Excel document stored in the app's local Documents folder.

I can use either:

```
[webView loadData:documentData MIMEType:mimeType textEncodingName:textEncoding baseURL:baseDocumentURL];
```

Or:

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:baseDocumentURL]];
```

In both cases, `baseDocumentURL` is a `file://` URL pointed at a file in the app's local Documents folder.

**ISSUE**

If I try to view an ***encrypted*** Word or Excel document — by either `-loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL:` or by `-loadRequest:` — my app throws an exception and crashes.

If I view the document through a web server, via Mobile Safari, the Safari browser displays the following error message:

[image]

My own `UIWebView` crashes while Mobile Safari works. What am I missing in setting up my web view that is causing an exception to be thrown?

Comment: iam into a similar problem, but i can't figure out, how to get the textEncoding for file (for most its utf-8, but not for all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some progress:

If I disable the `objc_exception_throw` global breakpoint in Xcode, then my app's web view behaves like the Mobile Safari web view, showing the same "This document is encrypted and can't be opened." error within the view.

Question:

Is there a way to send credentials or other information that my `UIWebView` can use to decrypt the Office document before loading the URL?